# Is there any software that really disables laptop's touchpad?

Tags: laptop, mouse, touchpad

My laptop PC is a HP G5055EA and I tried some scripts and applications to disable its touchpad, but no one works permanently: some of this software disables touchpad only for a few minutes and others does nothing at all!

Comment: Doesn't the laptop have a keyboard-combo for disabling the touchpad (like Fn + F1)?

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop should have a key combination to disable the touchpad still if you are asking for a software then you can search in the **software centre** for **pointing devices** and install that.

you'll find it in **system > preferences > pointing devices**

there you'll find the option to **disable touchpad** under **General** tab

Comment: this software would be your best choice cause it has some other choice to configure your pointing devices (touchpad).

Comment: Gaurav, you probably mean "gpointing-device-settings".  I have already installed this, but it doesn't work: though touchpad is "off", it still works!  Seems like this software cannot overcome the default settings (a script, maybe?) for the touchpad...

Comment: weird. Worked on mine.

Answer (score 2):

Many laptops have a hotkey (Fn + Touchpad key) which should Switch On/Off a touchpad under Ubuntu as well (like it works in Windows systems). However, such keys combination doesn't work in my Asus K52F (which has a new i3 Intel chipset).

I found that Jupiter applet [link text](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/02/jupiter-awesome-netbook-powerconfig-applet/) works very well in my case.

Comment: Jupiter seems to work and managed to disable touchpad... Drawback is that Jupiter must be runing for the touchpad to stay disabled, which is resource consumable...

Comment: I like Jupiter not only because of its touchpad management, but for power management and dual display features.

Comment: Thank you for Jupiter, was struggling with my Lenovo SL500 for almost a year now - nothing helped. But this thing works like a charm

Comment: Welcome German ! I am using Jupiter for about 8 month. It works very well on my Asus K52F.